# How do I fix Error in Random Forest model

Tags: r, random-forest, biomod2

I'm trying to run my SDM by package `biomod2` in R, but the random forest model showed the error that

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 572.0 Mb
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'predict': object 'model.bm' not found
```

this is my code

```
myBiomodModelOut<-BIOMOD_Modeling( myBiomodData,
                                   models = c('GLM','GBM','GAM','CTA','ANN','SRE','FDA','RF','MAXENT.Phillips'),
                                   models.options = myBiomodOption,
                                   NbRunEval = 3,
                                   DataSplit = 80,
                                   Prevalence = 0.5,
                                   VarImport = 3,
                                   models.eval.meth = c('KAPPA','TSS','ROC','FAR','SR','ACCURACY','BIAS','POD','CSI','ETS'),
                                   SaveObj = TRUE,
                                   rescal.all.models = TRUE,
                                   do.full.models = FALSE,
                                   modeling.id = paste(myRespName,"FirstModeling",sep=""))
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This usually means that your data is too big to be handled by your computer, i.e you habe not enough memory.

Comment: my computer has 8 GB of memory. What  I can do?

Comment: Are you using a 64bit version of R?